# How to get mouse position in characters inside textarea with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, dom-events

I am implementing drag'n'drop functionality on the page. The idea is that user can start dragging image from special place and drop it (release left mouse button) inside textarea, where special tag insertion will occur.
I have no issues with the dragging itself, the problem I got is that I can't determine position of the mouse inside textarea. I know `x` and `y` positions from `mouseup` event and I definetely know the mouse pointer is inside textarea, but can't determine at which position do I need to insert the required tag. Since the focus is not inside the textarea, `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties are 0. Also, it is worth noticing that I prevent default behavior by returning `false` in `mousemove` handler - otherwise default behavior will put the image itself inside the textarea (which is extremely bad for base64 images).
Below is the code I currently have.

```
window.onPreviewItemMouseDown = function (e) {
        var curTarget = $(e.currentTarget);
        var container = curTarget.parent();
        window.draggingImage = funcToGetId();
        $(document).on("mousemove", window.onPreviewItemDragged);
        $(document).on("mouseup", window.onPreviewItemDropped);
    };

window.onPreviewItemDragged = function (e) {
    return false;
};

window.onPreviewItemDropped = function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    $(document).off("mousemove");
    $(document).off("mouseup");
    if (target[0].id === ID_TEXTAREA_TEXT) {
        // here I need to get mouse pointer position inside the text somehow
    }

    return false;
};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Teemu I try to insert just tag for image, like `[img]image_id[/img]`, not the image body itself. This is used to display images later inside the text (in articles), this textarea is for editing the text of the article.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, that's why I removed my comment.

Comment: How about using [a native DOM event](http://jsfiddle.net/a98bwb07/1/)? In the fiddle just drag and drop the image to the textarea and check where and what is placed. (It seems that jQuery doesn't pass `e.dataTransfer` object, hence the native handling.)

Comment: @Teemu In this case it inserts content of `src` tag inside the text. It can be applicable for future parsing when the content of `src` is URL. However, when inside `src` is base64, then it inserts all the content there. Also, it the image is large (1 MB and more), then Chrome crashes when you try to do it. This is why I `return false` from the `mousemove` handler.

Comment: Currently the only one solution I have is to load all the images to server and use then links inside `src` in order to drag'n'drop images. After that parse content of textarea and replace with correct tags.

Comment: Well, you didn't check what the code actually is doing, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/a98bwb07/3/) another ; ).

Comment: @Teemu It works, please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case it would be easier to use native `ondragstart` event instead of a complex mousedown-move-up implementation, and manipulate the data to drop. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('img').addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text", '[img]' + this.id + '[/img]');
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a98bwb07/3/). Or [a delegated version](http://jsfiddle.net/a98bwb07/4/). Notice that you can also delegate to the "special place" element, which might make the page running a little bit faster.

Comment: Just to add. There is a case, when I would like to deny dragging operation, because when there is too large image in base64 inside `src`, Chrome crashes. So for this case I would also add `mousedown` handler, from which I'd `return false` for such images. For all other cases your solution suits perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: You can do a size check within `dragstart` handler as well. If the image is too large, set the data to `""`. Or you could attach an `ondrop` handler to `textarea`, and cancel the dropping, if the image is too large.